# Trying to find a pixel within a specific range (using for loop) using OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have been trying to figure this out for some time and have gotten stuck. I would appreciate any help.

```py
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(res_gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# something to notify us of black or white (after threshold application)
flag = 255
#for loop to find white pixel (scanning columns first - after 100)
for j in range (100, thresh.shape[1]): 
    if flag == 0: # check for 'found'
        break 
    for i in range (0, thresh.shape[0]): 
        if thresh[i,j] == 255:
            # once black is found, log starting coordinates
            starting_Y, starting_X = j, i
            # now we are looking for white
            flag = 0
            break

lower_blue = np.array([70,50,50])
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
```

Above is an example of the code I wrote to find white pixels within an binary image. It returns `j`,`i` which are the coordinates of the first white pixel found by scanning columns (and then rows) (starting from column 100). I would like to find cells within a HSV image which fall within a specific range. That range is `lower_blue` and `upper_blue`.

Comment: use `cv2.inRange`

Comment: Also, use [`numpy.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) to find the coordinates of the white pixels, i.e. `np.argwhere(thresh == 255)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looping over the image is extremely inefficient when using numpy arrays.There are far better efficient ways to perform above operation. Just search about slicing and indexing numpy arrays. 
To find white pixel,

```
    white_pixels = thresh == 0
```

this would return a Boolean array of same shape as the thresh with True at the places with white pixels and false otherwise. Use the same approach to find pixels within the required range. You can go through numpy documents to learn more about slicing and indexing arrays